# Extracting data from old Mac resource files

Tags: mac, file-conversion

What utility or tool that runs which under Mac OS X 10.6 can I use to extract data (icon images and strings, etc.) from old Mac OS 7 (and earlier) resource files/resource forks?  (...files created using ResEdit.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Rezycle](http://evolutioninteractive.com/rezycle/rezycle.html) might work for you. Let us know.

Comment: No longer supported by current macOS.I'd pay you for this still if it got recompiled for the newest macOS.

Answer (score 3):

On OSX you can access the raw resource fork of a file like this:

```
cp resource_file/..namedfork/rsrc  resource_fork
```

There's also the system utilities DeRez/Rez (available in OSX 10.7 and as mention by @marc as part of Xcode tools on newer MacOS versions) which allows for extraction of resource fork data into a form for use by the `Rez` resource compiler  - e.g. extract icon data from an Icon file:

```
DeRez -only icns Icon^M > icon
```

It should be noted that the resulting files from both of the above commands require additional processing to convert the resources to a suitable form.

See [related question](https://superuser.com/questions/298785/icon-file-on-os-x-desktop) on Icon files.

Comment: `DeRez` and `Rez` were deprecated with Xcode 6 (which deprecated all Carbon tools). However, `DeRez` and `Rez` are still available on macOS Monterey with Xcode 13.4 tools. `DeRez` extracts an icns resource in text form. Including the "additional processing" steps in the shown `icns` example would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Abet slightly unstable, the resource editor [Rezilla](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rezilla) runs under 10.7.4.